# Vaadin SuperDevMode recompilation fails sometimes, Widget is not rendered as it should and Java code for the Widget is not available

Tags: java, gwt, vaadin, gwt-super-dev-mode

I am trying to set up the SuperDevMode on a Vaadin project.

I have basically 3 problems related to this feature.

I have the following widget (created using the "New Vaadin Widget" wizard, below the code for the client-side widget, connector, state and server-side component):

```
// Widget:
public class CountedTextFieldWidget extends Composite {

    private TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
    private Label countLabel = new Label("0");
    private HorizontalPanel panel = new HorizontalPanel();

    public static final String CLASSNAME = "countedtextfield";

    public CountedTextFieldWidget() {
        initWidget(panel);
        setStylePrimaryName(CLASSNAME);
        textBox.setStylePrimaryName(CLASSNAME + "-field");
        countLabel.setStylePrimaryName(CLASSNAME + "-label");
        setStylePrimaryName(CLASSNAME);
        panel.add(textBox);
        panel.add(countLabel);
    }

    public String getText() {
        return textBox.getText();
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        textBox.setText(text);
    }

    public void setCount(int count) {
        countLabel.setText("" + count);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return Integer.parseInt(countLabel.getText());
    }

    // HandlerRegistration can be used to remove the key up handler (listener) 
    // added with this method
    public HandlerRegistration addKeyUpHandler(KeyUpHandler handler) {
        return textBox.addKeyUpHandler(handler);
    }

}

/********************************************************/
// Connector:
@Connect(CountedTextField.class)
public class CountedTextFieldConnector extends AbstractComponentConnector {

    public CountedTextFieldConnector() {
        getWidget().addKeyUpHandler(new KeyUpHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onKeyUp(KeyUpEvent event) {
                String text = getWidget().getText();
                getWidget().setCount(text.length());
            }           
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected Widget createWidget() {
        return GWT.create(CountedTextFieldWidget.class);
    }

    @Override
    public CountedTextFieldWidget getWidget() {
        return (CountedTextFieldWidget) super.getWidget();
    }

    @Override
    public CountedTextFieldState getState() {
        return (CountedTextFieldState) super.getState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStateChanged(StateChangeEvent stateChangeEvent) {
        super.onStateChanged(stateChangeEvent);

        final String text = getState().text;
        getWidget().setText(text);
        getWidget().setCount(text.length());
    }

}

/********************************************************/
// State

public class CountedTextFieldState extends com.vaadin.shared.ui.textfield.AbstractTextFieldState {

    {
        primaryStyleName = null;
    }
}

/********************************************************/
// Server-side component:
public class CountedTextField extends com.vaadin.ui.TextField {

    @Override
    public String getValue() {
        return getState().text;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        getState().text = value;
    }

    @Override
    public CountedTextFieldState getState() {
        return (CountedTextFieldState) super.getState();
    }
}
```

This widget is rendered as following:

[image]

Now, I have followed the following guide on the Vaadin's wiki:

https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Using%20SuperDevMode

The CodeServer starts as expected:

```
The code server is ready.
Next, visit: http://localhost:9876/
```

But when I open the project and append `?superdevmode` to the URL, get the `Recompilation failed...` message and there's are some errors in the browser's console:

[image]

[image]

So my first problem is related to this issue:

1) Why does recompilation fail sometimes? And what are those `SEVERE: JSONP compile call failed` and `SEVERE: Timeout Excecution`?

Then if I `... click to retry` sometimes the superdevmode starts, but the custom widget is not rendered as in the previous screenshot I posted.
Instead, I get a standard Vaadin's v-textfield...

[image]

2) WTF... Why? Where is my custom component?

I noticed that I get the same issue also if I open `localhost:9876`, drag the `Dev Mode On` button to the bookmarks toolbar and then click on it while on `localhost:8080/project`. My custom widget is disappears and instead I get the Vaadin's v-textfield widget...

And about the `Enable Source Map` feature. On the wiki, they say:

> To be able to debug Java code in Chrome, open the Chrome Inspector
>   (right click -> Inspect Element), click the settings icon in the lower
>   corner of the window and check "Scripts -> Enable source maps".
>   Refresh the page with the inspector open and you will see Java code
>   instead of JavaScript code in the scripts tab.

In my Chrome, I don't have a settings icon on the lower corner of the window, I clicked the gear icon on the right and went to `General -> Sources` and checked `Enable JavaScript Source Map` (There's no generic `Enable source maps` entry on my settings tab).

I can see the Java sources, but they are all sources for GWT and Vaadin's components:

[image]

So my third issue and related question:

3) How can I see my custom widget code also?

Thanks for the attention! Hope I was clear.

Comment: I am having the same problem. If you have solved this issue and still remember how, would you be so kind as to provide the answer?

Comment: Hi, well it has been a long ago. But I guess I didn't find a solution at that time. Otherwise I would have posted it here! So, if you find a solution, post it as an answer and I will accept it ;)

Comment: Too bad, but of course I will share if, or once I find the solution

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar problem trying to use SuperDev Mode with Vaadin. I'm not quite sure why recompilation fails on occasion, but I suspect it envolves the same issue I had trying to send my Java source maps. The problem I had seemed to be a caching issue due to the fact that the code server creates a persistent cache directory in my /tmp folder. So I deleted every folder it created (they usually have "gwt" in the name somewhere) and relaunched the code server. I suggest also adding the `-src <complete-path-to-project>` argument in the code server configurations to specify the directory containing GWT source to be prepended to the classpath for compiling and possibly changing the log level to `TRACE` or `DEBUG`. Heres an example those arguments:

```
com.example.AppWidgetSet -src /home/workspace/widgetset/src/main/java 
-logLevel TRACE
```

I should mention that the log levels are quite verbose, but can be quite useful. The log should also show the location of the cache folder.